# how to show/open colorbox only in specific pages

Tags: javascript, colorbox

i have a common.js library that give all the javascript code i need for my site from one file.
The thing is that i have the following code in that file and is opening in every page but i need to open in only when the visiotr opening a specific page.

```
// open thickbox    
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
$('a.js-thickbox-subscribe').fcolorbox2();    
});    

$.fn.fcolorbox2 = function() {    
 if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -1) {    
    var expires = new Date();    
    expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+30);    
    document.cookie = "visited=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();    
    $.colorbox( {    
            inline:true,    
            overlayClose: false,    
            fixed: true,    
            href:'#test',    
            width:'700px',    
            height:'500px',    
        });    
 }    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a value only on those pages that you want the color box to open on.

There are many different values you can set and check..

- A class name on the `body` element.
- A set Javascript variable.
- A `data-*` attribute on the body element
- A configuration object, specific to each page.